# HTTP Status 404 when running java SendMail

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I'm getting the following error:

```
address bar: http://localhost:8080/EmailNew/WEB-INF/classes/SendMail.java

HTTP Status 404 -
type Status report
message
description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
```

from running the code below from Eclipse EE and Tomcat 8.

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;





public class SendMail {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();

    /*  props.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    */
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");




        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("abcxyz@gmail.com","xdkasaspajokzfcr");
            }
        };

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth);

        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        try {
            msg.setSubject("Email Test");
            msg.setText("We made it!!");
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("abcxyz@gmail.com","Bob"));
            msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("abcxyz@gmail.com"));

            Transport.send(msg);
        } catch (MessagingException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Finished.");
    }

}
```

Comment: Please don't post your email/password in a pubic forum.

Comment: Also include the exception stacktrace in the post.

Comment: I'm not getting a stacktrace.  I don't think the code is executing

Comment: where do you get "HTTP Status 404" ?

Comment: my crome browser opens and I get the message

Comment: How are you running the Java file ?

Comment: I'm running it on Eclipse EE.  I stop the server, clean, then run on server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96476/discussion-between-11thdimension-and-dcr).